# On customer address save, get origin data

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, model, customer-address, save

I'm working on an observer of the `customer_address_save_before` event. On customer address saving, i've to check if there's changes before doing some actions.

I did something similar for the `customer/customer` model with some natives methods such as `hasDataChanges()`, `dataHasChangedFor($key)` and `getOrigData()` from the `Varien_Object` class.

However, when i tried to do it for the `customer/address` model, i figured out that the `_origData` property is null. This happens only when the customer address is updated in the front-end. When i update the customer address in the back-end, i do have the correct `_origData`.

Do you know why does this happen and how to fix or bypass this ?

Comment: Where have you defined your event? Inside the <global> tag or within the <frontend>?

Comment: Inside the global one. It seems like i'm not the only one who have this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414610/viewing-magento-model-data-changes-on-before-after-save-event. But i can't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue a few weeks ago so i'm going to give my solution as it could helps anyone :

```
public function onCustomerAddressSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customerAddress = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerAddress();

    /*
     * If the customer address exists, as $_origData of customer's address is sometimes null, we have to set it manually
     */
    if (!$customerAddress->isObjectNew() && !$customerAddress->getOrigData()) {
        $customerOrigAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddress->getId());

        foreach ($customerOrigAddress->getData() as $field => $value) {
            $customerAddress->setOrigData($field, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

As you might guess, the `onCustomerAddressSaveBefore()` method is triggered on `customer_address_save_before` event. Inside it, i check if the object is not new (there's no original data for a new object) and if the object doesn't contain `_origData` yet. If these conditions are true, then i manually set the `_origData` by getting them from the database.